# How to Slice a DataFrame by Index inside a Nested Loop using a Loop Variable

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I need some help with slicing and indexing using Pandas Dataframes. I have a dataframe, p_df, which needs some slicing.  Basically, I need to slice my data and export two rows and two columns at a time to a .txt file and name the .txt file with the index name. I’d like to nest it inside a loop so that it grabs only 2 rows at a time (there are only 2 columns of data right now but I’m wanting to possibly add more later).  An example of my data is below:

```
          model     weight   price
0           210     412.0       535.041274
1           210     460.0      535.041274
2           221     399.0          1598.878982
3           221     442.5       1598.878982
4           222     437.0       122338.608200
5           222      440.0      122338.608200
```

I’d like to get the first two .txt files to simply say:

```
Name: 210.txt
412.0   535.041274
460.0   535.041274
```

So far, I’m working with some code I’m trying to modify to do this:

```
i=0
for index, row in p_df.iterrows():
    if i > len(p_df):
       break
    else:
       f = open(str(i)+'.txt', 'w')
       f.write(row[0:1])
       f.close()
       i+=2
```

Any help is tremendously appreciated!

Comment: try this? `for k,v in df.groupby("model"): v.drop("model",1).to_csv(f"{your_folder_path}{k}.txt",sep='\t',index=False)`

Comment: Will the data frame always contain even number of rows?